# Regex pattern for multiple optional capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract some data from the text which has following patterns.

```
text1
text1|text2
text1|text2[text3]
text1|text2[text3] text4
(text1|text2[text3], text4)
text1[text3]
text1[text3], text4
```

So far I managed to construct two expressions and when the first one fails it falls back on the second.

`/\(?([^|[]*)\|?([^[]*)\[?(.*)\],?\s?([^)]*)\)?/`

`/([^|]*)\|?(.*)/`

Perhaps there is better way to parse it.

Is it possible to capture everything above with one regex?

Thanks for help

**Example**

```js
const items = [
"text1",
"text1|text2",
"text1|text2[text3]",
"text1|text2[text3] text4",
"(text1|text2[text3], text4)",
"text1[text3]",
"text1[text3], text4"
]

const parse = (text) => {

const [_, text1, text2, text3, text4] = /\(?([^|[]*)\|?([^[]*)\[?(.*)\],?\s?([^)]*)\)?/.exec(text)
|| /([^|]*)\|?(.*)/.exec(text)

  return {
    text1,
    text2,
    text3,
    text4
  };
}

for(const text of items) {
   console.log(parse(text));
}
```

Comment: Would you consider a split using `/[(),|\s\[\]]+/`

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use `text.match(/\w+/g)`?

Comment: I tried both regexes and they work fine but I also need the information which capture group matched. For example I can't distinguish `text1[text3]` from `text1|text2`. Sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const items = [
"text1",
"text1|text2",
"text1|text2[text3]",
"text1|text2[text3] text4",
"(text1|text2[text3], text4)",
"text1[text3]",
"text1[text3], text4"
]

const parse = (text) => {

const [_, text1, text2, text3, text4] = /^\(?([^[|]+)(?:\|([^[]+))?(?:\[([^\][]*)](?:\s*(?:,\s*)?([^\s)].*?))?)?\)?$/.exec(text)

  return {
    text1,
    text2,
    text3,
    text4
  };
}

for(const text of items) {
   console.log(text, parse(text));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cc1EH6/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\(?` - an optional `)`
- `([^[|]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `[` and `|`
- `(?:\|([^[]+))?` - an optional sequence of `|` and then Group 2: any one or more chars other than `[` as many as possible
- `(?:\[([^\][]*)](?:\s*(?:,\s*)?([^\s)].*?))?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\[([^\][]*)]` - `[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (captured into Group 3) and then a `]`
  - `(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?([^\s)].*?))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
    - `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and zero or more whitespace chars
    - `([^\s)].*?)` - Group 4: a char other than whitespace and `)` and then zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `$` -  end of string.